# Changing the look of Youtube

Tags: colors, youtube

So i kind of want a way to change the look of youtube in my screen. Like the way it looks is fine rn ig, but it would be cool if i could change it to something more personalized or something like that. There are 2 totally major things i wanna do.

first, I like their fonts and everything but a more swirly font like rochester would be so cool

also like red isn't really my color so it would be cool if i could change that to a nice pinkish orange or something like that

im not that good at coding and stuff but i would assume this would be pretty easy. like i got the colors to change in a cool game i found in python by just changing the numbers at the top. i would think that the font thing would be easy too by just changing a variable somewhere.

I was all hyped about doing this but i couldnt find the code to youtube anywhere online for download or in any of my folders on my computer and i was kind of confused bc someone must have done what i want to do before so i came here to ask you guys.

thx in advance!

Comment: Use a browser addon which allows custom styling like [this one](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/?src=search)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Youtube.com using Chrome as your browser. Right click anywhere one the page and select `inspect`. This will open up Dev Tools. You can change colors. Edit HTML. Run JavaScript. Whatever you want.